# iOS: change view from viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm playing around with view life cycles & am having trouble changing a view from the load of a different view.

In my ViewController.h i have:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *viewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However this only causes the view to be between ViewController, and ViewController2 appearing with animation (in a loop).

I used the code in `viewDidLoad` however neither of the view's loaded (from reading you cannot change view until the viewWillAppear)

Update: When using the code in `viewWillAppear`, `whose view is not in the window hierarchy` error is thrown.

How does one change the view from view setup stage?

**Update**
Using the above code, inside & out of GCD, in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` & `viewDidAppear` either results in an infinite loop of animated showing of the ViewController2, or crash on 2nd attempt of segue (result from the loop).

Comment: What's the need in loading the first view?

Comment: "I'm playing around with view life cycles" 

there will a deterministic purpose for this later but for now its just to change a view from inside the initial view controller

Comment: I can see there is no `[super viewDidLoad];` in your `viewDidLoad` method. Put that code there and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but assuming you are wanting the first viewcontroller to appear and then the second viewcontroller to immediately animate on top of the first one, you should be able to accomplish using several options:

First you could just wrap your calls in a dispatch_async call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *viewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard 
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Or you could use a show modally segue:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myModalSegue" sender:self];
  });
}
```

Or you could use a navigation controller and use a standard show segue (formally push).  This one doesn't require the dispatch_async:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myshowsegue" sender:self];
}
```

I've posted working examples of all three on: [github](https://github.com/jdecarlo/StackOverFlow_change-view-from-viewDidAppear)

Comment: there's no real aim for this currently, but your method is certainly interesting. Although the navigation controller is not in use, would this literally place the ViewController2 ontop of the ViewController? (with some method of returning to the first ViewController) or does it change the view only (no link back to the First Viewcontroller.)

Comment: When you do presentViewController, it presents the view controller modally.  No Nav controller is necessary or in play at this point.  You could always pass a block to the presented view controller to execute.  And, Yes, it literally places it on top of the first view controller.

Comment: Incidentally, you could create a modal segue from the first view controller to the second and call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] to get the same effect.

Comment: When i try to use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` both with & without GCD, the first view loads, then the 2nd view loads with animation, then i recieve a crash. It almost looks like the changing of view, or segue in this case is in a loop. it then returns that the ViewController2 Doesn't have a segue by the name of the segue that ViewController uses, which is correct as i'm not calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` from ViewController2

Comment: Ahh...put it in viewDidLoad.  Sorry.. I didn't catch that.

Comment: still the exact same results as before. i'm thinking that as this loop effect is causing issues that there is something else wrong here. i think i need some form of check to call it when ready, potentially i think its called lazy load but i'm probaby wrong

Comment: I believe your solution is correct. My app has an infinite loop on `viewDidLoad` so the crash still occurs.

Comment: Just added working examples of both on github for you

Comment: Please select as answer if you think it is the correct solution

Comment: i want to select your answer (i do appreciate your help) But every time i implement the solutions i get the same problem of the loop on viewDidLoad, thus it isnt working.

Comment: in fact, your answer is the answer to this question. instead of trying to get this new issue resolved via this question i'll just accept this as you've pretty much answered my question in the best way possible

Comment: Have you looked at the project I posted on github?  You could compare what you have to it to try to find your issue.

Comment: i have and its the same. I've opened a new question if you were interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171860/ios-loop-on-viewdidload-unbalenced-calls

Answer (score 0):

It is better to exchange views in `loadView` method.

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    self.view = view;
}
```

Comment: i think this is a little too far back in the cycle for what i'm looking for. although not in the question, i'm looking for a way to change the view from the view loading/loaded methods so some per-determine code will inevitably determine which view to load

Comment: @Simon. Btw: "from the view loading/loaded methods" - this is exactly view loading method ;) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html