# iOS: loop on viewDidLoad unbalanced calls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two View Controllers. `ViewController` & `Next`.

**ViewContoller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    bool static check = FALSE;

    if(!check){
        check = true;
        [self changeView];
    }
}


-(void)changeView{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        Next *viewController = (Next *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"next"];

        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

**Next.m** is nothing more than the xcode boilerplate code of a view.

When i execute this as above, i receive this output:

```
2014-11-27 13:20:21.005 changeView[1804:72014] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController: 0x7fdd80f41e20>.
```

You'll notice that i have a static boolean in the viewDidLoad. Without this, the viewDidLoad is called infinitely causing an animated loop of Next's view appearing ontop of ViewController's view.

I'm almost 100% certain that i should not have to implement the boolean to prevent the loop but this is the only way i can. What do?

**Update!**
When i embed a navigation controller, and use `[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];` i do not experience the loop.

While this resolves the situation, the issue of changing views (without a navigation controller) still stands

Comment: What happens if you don't `presentViewController...` ?

Comment: elaborate on that please...

Comment: i've used [self showViewController:sender:] with the exact same results

Comment: Place a log in `changeView` and check if it is called repeatedly after commenting out the `presentViewController` code. Are you sure you have set the Storyboard ID correctly?

Comment: loop doesn't occur. What alternative options are available to me for presentViewController?

Comment: so far it seems that every attempt to change the viewcontroller causes the loop

Comment: Since I posted a solution for you and am not any any way able to recreate your looping issue, I have be believe the loop is being caused by something else in your code and is only manifesting itself when you do the presentViewController.

Comment: Why are you dispatching to the main queue, which you are already on, since you called changeView from viewDidLoad on the main thread?